# Geo spatial Fences Relation w.r.t Individual Devices?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, geospatial, iot, geofencing

I'm developing a Geo Tracking Mobile App with IBM IOT Service and IBM Geo spatial,
I'm Creating Fences for Devices as well, What i'm trying to do in this is to

**Create Geo fences for Specific Devices, so i only get Geo Alert for That Particulate device, not for all devices crossing that fence.**

Is there any Functionality in Geo Spatial Where i can assign/relate fences with Devices, and Achieve this.

*I'm already achieving this by Filtering out the alerts when received, but can it be achieved on IOT/Geo Spatial Service Side.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the Geo service that allows you to relate fences to particular devices.  So filtering of the alerts is probably the most straightforward way to solve this.

Another option would be to have multiple instances of the Geo service.  This approach would only make sense if there were groups of devices that needed to be related to one or more fences.

For example, if you were tracking 1000 devices and there was a group of 250 devices that certain fences only apply to, you could use a different instance of the Geo service to register fences specific to that group.  All of the Geo instances would subscribe to the same feed from IoT, but each instance would have its own set of fences.  (But the mapping is 1:1, i.e., you want a fence that only applies for one device, this approach wouldn't be suitable.)